# Comparing two lists to get objects that appear in both

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have two lists of the same class, and want to generate a count of objects that appear in both lists.

```
Dim repeatingMentions As Integer 
repeatingMentions =currentMentions.Where(Function(m) previousMentions.Contains(m)).Count
```

Debugging I can see that the two lists contain objects with exactly the same property values, is this enough to satisfy contains because the count is coming back as 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` or provide a custom `IEqualityComparer(Of YourClassName)` to make this work with `Contains`. Or you have to use `Any`:

```
repeatingMentions  = currentMentions.
    Count(Function(m) previousMentions.
        Any(Function(p) m.PropertyName = p.PropertyName))
```

or you could join both lists via `Enumerable.Join`:

```
Dim inBoth = From currMent In currentMentions
             Join prevMent In previousMentions
             On currMent.PropertyName Equals prevMent.PropertyName
repeatingMentions = inBoth.Count()
```

Comment: Thanks, accepted as this answers the original question and has alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method from Linq to find the intersection in two sequences, then call `Count` method to count it.

```
repeatingMentions = currentMentions.Intersect(previousMentions).Count()
```

Note that above method compares the instances by references by default. If you want custom implementation you need to use [this overload of Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355408%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which takes `IEqualityComparer` as parameter.

Comment: This won't work as the class doesn't seem to override `Equals` + `GetHashCode`(_" contain objects with exactly the same property values,... count is coming back as 0."_)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was updating my answer, Added a caveat about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, of course the references would be different so the count is correct. Im going to add my own comparer and see how that works out

Answer (score 0):

Let `a()` and `b()` are two integer arrays, you can select the count of common elements in both the arrays using the code below. same as in the case of string arrays also.

```
    Dim a As Integer() = {1, 5, 2, 3, 6, 4, 7, 89, 5, 8}
    Dim b As Integer() = {4, 78, 85, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8}
    Dim count As Integer = a.Intersect(b).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intersect extension method for this.(You might have to reference it by referencing the namespace System.Linq)

An Example with a list of strings.

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
List<string> b = new List<string>();

var result =  a.Intersect(b);
```

Depending on your object you should implement a IEqualityComparer and pass it to the intersect method to correctly compare the object (implements Equals and getHash)